# MongoDB Mobile (in beta) and Nativescript on Android

Tags: android, mongodb, mobile, nativescript

I'm starting a new project using **Mongodb Stitch**, which is a Backend as a Service. There is a new product call **MongoDB Mobile** (synchronizable local db ) and looks very interesting, but only works for Android and iOS and I don't have much experience in native development, just Web skills. Apparently **NativeScript** can communicate with native API of both planforms through javascript. Anyone with experience with NativeScript who has played with these services on Android?. Will it be possible to install it and make it work?

Comment: You can write a plugin to do that. What you have to do is to define what are the functions you need, you write a single interface for both platforms, then you implement the logic using native code (you need android and ios skills to do that part) for each platform. Once it is done, you will call the interface functions and nativescript will use iOS or Android implementation depending on the platform the app runs on. There is a lot of plugin that maps native SDK and there is docs for plugin, and a base repository called nativescript-plugin-seed.

Comment: thanks Florian, I'll watch it